# Circular Image View with overlapping text ( Click able )

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

I want to create a button which should be like the sample image. Circular Image View with overlapping text ( Clickable ).I have tried some libraries but none of them offer android:text="something" function.

Is there any library that offers them both together?

```
  <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">
  <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp">
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/tem_hashtag_bn_04"
                        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**Click able Circular Image View**

[image: Click able Circular Image View]

Comment: @NileshRathod, Did it by mistake. 
btw please help me with another question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/52534880/10323427?sem=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myCircleImageView"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cmll_completed_per"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myCircleImageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myCircleImageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/myCircleImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/myCircleImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="100%" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a FrameLayout be more efficient and easier to work with?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/speaker_avatar_container"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeholder"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

and create a circle.xml and paste

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

I got this answer from [enter link description here](https://android.jlelse.eu/avatarview-custom-implementation-of-imageview-4bcf0714d09d)

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Nilesh Rathod worked out well, just modified a bit for my requirements.

[image: solved].

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="2dp"

                        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/profile_image1"
                            android:layout_width="96dp"
                            android:layout_height="96dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/tem_hashtag_bn_04"
                            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
                        <TextView

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profile_image1"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/profile_image1"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@id/profile_image1"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/profile_image1"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:text="100%" />
                    </RelativeLayout>**strong text**
```